# If a CORS preflight failed, will the real request be sent?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, browser, cors

If a CORS preflight failed, will the real request be sent?

1. The browser didn't send a real request at all?
2. The browser still send the real request, but the response was intercepted?

Comment: Of course it doesn’t send the request, otherwise that would be a way that you could _undermine_ CORS and still get clients to send requests they should not be permitted to make in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

the preflight request is for ask server to send a real request with CORS, if the preflight request doesn't pass the server send an error and the real request was blocked.